# Não efetua o redirecionamento após a chamada de serviço no angular?

Tags: angular

Quando faço a chamada ele passa direto pelo Subscribe e redireciona para a rota login quando na verdade deveria ir para **/criar-conta/bem-vindo**, os dados não foram inseridos na tabela do banco.

Eu tenho o seguinte metodo:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.spiner.show();
    this.form.markAllAsTouched();

    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    this.http.post(SELLER_URL, this.form.value, this.httpOptions)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.storageService.clear();
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/criar-conta/bem-vindo');
      },
        error => {
          console.log('oops', error.error);
          this.erro = error.error;
        }
      ).add(() => this.spiner.hide());
  }
```

Essa é a parte mais interessante. Não tem nenhum Guard e nem injeção do guard no componente!

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { BrowserStorageService } from 'src/app/shared/services/browser-storage.service';
import { Utils } from 'src/app/shared/utils/utils';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

const SELLER_URL = environment.apiUrl + '/api/sellers';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-passo-tres',
  templateUrl: './passo-tres.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./passo-tres.component.scss']
})
export class PassoTresComponent implements OnInit {
  email: string = this.storageService.get('email');
  erro: false;
  httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        //'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        //'Content-Type': ' multipart/form-data',
        //'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      })
    }

  form = this.fb.group({
    senha: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
    confirmacaoSenha: ['', Validators.required],
    isSeller: [this.storageService.get('isSeller')],
    nome: [this.storageService.get('nome')],
    email: [this.storageService.get('email')],
    numero: [this.storageService.get('numero')],
    cpf: [this.storageService.get('cpf')],
    possuiContaBancariaCNPJ: [this.storageService.get('possuiContaBancariaCNPJ')],
    possuiNf: [this.storageService.get('possuiNf')],
    atendeDimensoesMaxPacote: [this.storageService.get('atendeDimensoesMaxPacote')],
    categoriaSellerId: [this.storageService.get('categoriaSellerId')]
  }, { validators: this.utils.passwordsValidate });

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private storageService: BrowserStorageService,
    private utils: Utils,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
    private spiner: NgxSpinnerService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  get controls() {
    return this.form.controls;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.spiner.show();
    this.form.markAllAsTouched();

    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    this.http.post(SELLER_URL, this.form.value, this.httpOptions)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.storageService.clear();
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/criar-conta/bem-vindo');
      },
        error => {
          console.log('oops', error.error);
          this.erro = error.error;
        }
      ).add(() => this.spiner.hide());
  }

  voltar() {
    history.back();
  }

}
```

Essse acima  é o componente inteiro
Abaixo as rotas já que @rmgimenez pens

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path: '', component: CadastroFormComponent },
      { path: 'passos', component: PassosComponent },
      { path: 'passos/passo-um', component: PassoUmComponent },
      { path: 'passos/passo-dois', component: PassoDoisComponent },
      { path: 'passos/passo-tres', component: PassoTresComponent },
    ]
  },
  { path: 'bem-vindo', component: ContaCriadaComponent }
];
```

Alguém sabe o que está ocorrendo? É possível que haja alguma outra forma para resolver isso no angular.

Comment: Verifique se tem algum guard rodando para essa rota

Comment: Consegue coloca mais detalhes, fica meio complicado sabe como vc esta gerenciando essas rotas